# Assigning form value from values within an array

Tags: reactjs

I have a table that has an edit button next to each row. I send the persons id to the form component and get their data from the DB using the id. I assign it to patient. I then want to use the data to autofill a form.

Here is the top of the file.

```
class PtEditForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //console.log(this.props.location.search);
    const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    console.log(query.patientId);

    this.state = {
      ptId: query.patientId || null,
      patient: null
    };
```

Here is the fetch that I confirm works when I log it.

```
  getPatient() {
    fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/PtEditPg/" + this.state.ptId)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ patient: data }));
  }
```

Here is the one of the forms showing what I have attempted

```
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input
                type="Name"
                className="form-control"
                id="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                placeholder="First Name"
                value={this.state.patient.firstName}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
```

Comment: Whats's the issue?

Comment: Yeah this looks good, do you have any errors?

Comment: I’m getting back that the value is unassigned.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaDickson. I think that JS will already be crashing and there would be some errors at your console. Reason being you have initialized patient with null and value that you are giving in input from state is `this.state.patient.firstName`. Now here JS would break when it resolves to `null.firstName`. 


On first Render of the input tag, when patient doesn't has any value from API, this will be the case. 

I suggest, you initialize  patient with empty object.

Comment: Can you pull a fidde for it?

Comment: @Mobeen I have fiddler but I'm not sure how to use it. I initialized patient as an object with the same result. To be clear, I am not getting any errors. It just shows that `this.state.patient.firstName` is undefined. When I log `this.state.patient` I get this in dev tools: [{…}]
0: {patientId: 1, firstName: "Josh", lastName: "Smith", dob: "1991-06-03", addressLine1: "2005 Capewood", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Hi  @joshua , in that case, please assign data[0] in setState method

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The object was an array I think?

This is what worked

```
this.state.patient[0].firstName
```